# Custom hook with array props is making infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I know there is a lot of similar questions here but I haven't been able to find an answer that makes me realise what I am doing wrong here.

I've made a custom hook called `useAmounts` which can translate text like `5%` into `0.05` or `500` into `500,000,000` if the current state had million as a multiplier. I need this for multiple inputs in various components.

I've also made another hook called `useMerged` which basically have an array of input data, e.g `"5%", "200 million"` plus some additional data. That hook should then merged the parsed numbers into desired object.

In the end I want a list of objects where I can retrieve the values and functions to update the values inside the list. But I am getting infinite loops.

I've tried to make a minimal example but it does its hard to keep it completely minimal for the pattern I am looking for. Any help is much appreciated! My guess is that there is a far better pattern to achieve what I am trying here.

```js
import * as React from "react";

interface Amount {
  multiplier: number;
  displayText: string;
  value: number;
  updateAmount: (text: string) => void;
}

function useAmounts(initialValues: string[]): Amount[] {
  const [amounts, setAmounts] = React.useState<
    {
      multiplier: number;
      displayText: string;
      value: number;
    }[]
  >([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(
      `useAmounts: Setting initial amounts of length ${initialValues.length}`
    );
    setAmounts(
      initialValues.map(text => {
        const matches = text.match(/\d+/g);
        const multiplier = text.includes("%") ? 0.01 : 1;
        const displayText = matches ? matches[0] : "";
        return {
          multiplier,
          displayText,
          value: parseFloat(displayText) * multiplier
        };
      })
    );
  }, [initialValues]);

  const updateAmount = (index: number) => (text: string) => {
    const matches = text.match(/\d+/g);
    setAmounts(prevState => {
      const newState = [...prevState];
      newState[index].displayText = matches ? matches[0] : "";
      return newState;
    });
  };

  return amounts.map((a, index) => {
    return {
      multiplier: a.multiplier,
      displayText: a.displayText,
      value: a.value,
      updateAmount: updateAmount(index)
    };
  });
}

interface State {
  text: string;
  additionalValue: string;
}

interface MergedState {
  amount: {
    multiplier: number;
    displayText: string;
    value: number;
    updateAmount: (text: string) => void;
  };
  additionalValue: string;
}

function useMerged(states: State[]) {
  const [initialText, setInitialText] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
  const amounts = useAmounts(initialText);
  const [mergedState, setMergedState] = React.useState<MergedState[]>([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(
      `useMerged: setting initial input for useAmounts in useMerged of length ${
        states.length
      }`
    );
    setInitialText(states.map(v => v.text));
  }, [states]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (amounts.length === states.length)
      setMergedState(
        states.map((s, index) => {
          return {
            additionalValue: s.additionalValue,
            amount: amounts[index]
          };
        })
      );
  }, [amounts.length, states.length]);

  return mergedState;
}

const delayedInitialState: State[] = [
  { text: "100 million", additionalValue: "A" },
  { text: "25%", additionalValue: "B" }
];

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState<State[]>([]);
  const mergedStates = useMerged(state);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("App: setting initial state on app level");
    setState(delayedInitialState);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {mergedStates.map((a, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <input
              value={a.amount.displayText}
              onChange={event => a.amount.updateAmount(event.target.value)}
            />
            {a.amount.multiplier}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### EDIT

I am also puzzled about the lifecycle here. Console output:

1. useAmounts: Setting initial amounts of length 0
2. useMerged: setting initial input for useAmounts in useMerged of length 0
3. App: setting initial state on app level
4. useAmounts: Setting initial amounts of length 0
5. useMerged: setting initial input for useAmounts in useMerged of length 2
6. useAmounts: Setting initial amounts of length 2

Why does `useAmounts` render after `App` **before** `useMerged` have changed the initial input?

Comment: Your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: [How to do a runnable Stack Snippet with React, including JSX](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 1):

In your `useMerged` function, `amounts` will be a different reference every time you do `const amounts = useAmounts(states.map(v => v.text));`. What that means is that when you check in `useEffect` to see if `initialValues` has changed in your `useAmounts` function it will always see the new reference as a change.

One way of solving this - Can you instead just to `useAmounts(states)` and update your code to be a `State[]` instead of a `string[]`, instead calling `map` on it?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not a possibility but I was thinking that maybe I could use a stateful input instead, e.g. `const [initialText, setInitialText] = React.useState<string[]>([])`  and then `useEffect` to set the initial text and use `initialText` as input to `useAmount`. Unfortunately that doesn't work either (see updated code in original question)